# "to be used" vs "to being used"

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

I have the following sentence:

> The aggregator in the smart meter network has to provide incentive users
>   to contribute their smart meters **to being used** as relays.

Here, which one is better: "to being used" or "to be used"?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "The aggregator in the smart meter network has to provide an incentive for users to allow their smart meters to be used as relays."

Comment: @Hellion Or closer to the original, albeit ungrammatical form: *The aggregator, in the smart meter network, has to provide an incentive for users to contribute their smart meters for use as relays.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *fantastic* question.

You cannot *contribute something* while you can ***contribute something to something*** or ***contribute to something*** or ***contribute to doing something***.

[Read more here.](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/contribute)

I understand why you think it's a good idea to use a *passive gerund* instead of a *passive infinitive* and that's probably because of *to*. You probably think it's a preposition here. But you don't need to use a preposition there. However, you need to change the place of it and put it right after *contribute* so your phrase would be

> contribute to their smart meters

Now you want to say ***why** to contribute to their smart meters*. You need an infinitive to add a purpose. One of the usage of infinitive is to express the purpose either in active or passive voice. Then your final version of your sentence part would be

> ... contribute *to* their smart meters *to be used* as relays.

The *first to* is a preposition while *the second one* is part of the infinitive structure.

Comment: _Since you're not asking about the rest of the sentence, I'm not going to comment on that._

Comment: I don't think we really can discuss the OP's main point while ignoring the rest of the sentence. Hellion's comment is a good suggestion, in my opinion.

Comment: Yea, actually the sentence is faulty but I thought it would be a good idea to respond to his concern based on the usage of contribute.

Comment: I'm sorry, but even considering only the *contribute* part, I think you misunderstand the OP's intended meaning. "contribute to their smart meters to be used as relays" sounds weird, don't you think?

Comment: If we replace _contribute to_ with _help_, I think that would sound weird no more. Though yea I admit it demands an unusual context to sound usual.